# Append URL parameter to href with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to append a query string parameter to a href on a page using some JS:

```
var url = "http://www.sitetest.com?source=" + value;
var element = document.getElementById('thislink');
element.setAttribute("href",url);
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="thislink">TEST THIS LINK</a>
```

So whatever parameter is in the URL needs to append to the link, its working however it puts in the current URL not the one I specify in "var url"? Thanks!

Live link here: http://partnerweb.moneycorp.com/test-js-get-url.html?pc=tmgppc5

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined

Comment: If you want to mess around with javascript, you really should get Firebug or some other tool that shows the JS console.

Comment: No `value` --> No `url`

Comment: Why don't you go for string concatination in java script?

Comment: Checking for errors in your console should always be a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a value to the variable "value", it is currently undefined

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined
```

Example

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var value = "testValue";
  var url = "http://www.sitetest.com?source=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
  var element = document.getElementById('thislink');
  element.setAttribute("href",url);
});
```

You also want to use encodeURIComponent for any string values you are passing in a URL, to make sure it encodes special characters

Comment: Thanks, its defining "value" now, however there's another error in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null"

Comment: Move your javascript after the <p> tag and before the close of the </body> tag. Your are trying to access the DOM before it is ready. Or only run your code when the window is ready. Please see change above.

Comment: I see the solution has worked for you, please approve the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On your test page, have you checked the console?

`Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`

The posted code will work fine if you assign a value to the `value` variable.